# Need help in understanding definition of monomials

Tags: polynomials, terminology, definition, monomial-order, monomial-function

Wikipedia states two definitions of monomials-
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monomial

I have understood the first one but I am facing some problem in understanding the second one which says that-" A monomial is a monomial in **the first sense** multiplied by a nonzero constant, called the coefficient of the monomial. A monomial in the first sense is a special case of a monomial in **the second sense**, where the coefficient is 1."

***Someone please explain what this second definition is trying to say?
And,what is this first and the second sense in this definition?***

Wikipedia also mentioned this example in the second definition- For example, ***in this interpretation*** -7x^5 and (3-4i)x^4 * y*z^13  are monomials (in the second example, the variables are x,y,z and the coefficient is a complex number).

I just want to know to know what is ***the interpretation*** they are talking about?

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Interpretation", here, refers to "the meaning we give to the term 'monomial'".

The article is discussing two different possible meanings that are commonly assigned to the term. Under both, $x^3 y^7$ is a monomial. $3x^3 y^7$ is only a monomial for one of them. $x^3 + y^7$ is not a monomial for either.